# Is SQLite database support MEDIUMTEXT like MySQL in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have seen that MySQL is supporting the MEDIUMTEXT which can store around 16mb of data and LONGTEXT is supporting around 4gb of data. Does SQLite support mediumtext ?.  Thanks in advance....

Comment: No, SQLite only supports [a few data types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQLite has only [a single string data type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storageclasses).

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_length) says:

> **Maximum length of a string or BLOB**
>   The maximum number of bytes in a string or BLOB in SQLite is defined by the preprocessor macro SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH. The default value of this macro is 1 billion (1 thousand million or 1,000,000,000).